# Should queues be mutex protected?

Tags: freertos

reading examples on the internet I don't see that there is protection around queues in FreeRTOS. Are they somehow protected or should I protect them with mutexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the RTOS objects are completely thread safe (as would be expected).  You can read the documentation and follow the examples - of which there are lot: http://www.freertos.org/Embedded-RTOS-Queues.html

Answer (score 3):

It is not needed. Protection is included in the implementation of the queues. After all semaphores themselves are implemented as queues.